# Discard wrapper data when using Reads[T]

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I think what I'm trying to do should be relatively simple, but I'm not certain. I'm making an API call to get a list of applications and I'd like to read them out. However, the list is nested into the response. The response looks something like:

```
{
  "response": {
    "instances": [
      { /* object I'm concerned with reading */ },
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

I have a reader currently defined as:

```
implicit val appReader : Reads[App] = (
  (__ \ "ip_address").read[String] and
  (__ \ "hostname").read[String] and
  (__ \ "application_version").read[String]
)(App)
```

And a class of:

```
case class App(
    ip: String,
    hostname: String,
    version: String
)
```

However, I'm not sure of how to get at the data since it is buried in the response or if there is a way that I can discard that data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the applications lie within the instances array like this:

```
val js = Json.parse("""
           {
             "response": {
               "instances": [
                 { "ip_address": "192.168.1.1", "hostname": "host1", "application_version": "1.0"},
                 { "ip_address": "192.168.1.2", "hostname": "host2", "application_version": "1.0"}
               ]
             }
           }
           """)
```

Now, to read the list of applications defined as App:

```
val responseRead =
  (__ \ "response").read(
    (__ \ "instances").read[List[App]])

val apps = responseRead.reads(js).get
```

This gives you the list of applications leaving out the rest. If the data structure is somewhat different than assumed, this should point you in the right direction.

**Edit:** Most of the time I prefer to use the [Json macro inception](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJsonInception) of play. The code for your example could be written as follows:

```
case class App(
  ip_address: String,
  hostname: String,
  application_version: String)

object App {
  implicit val appFormat = Json.format[App]
}

case class Response(
  instances: List[App])

object Response {
  implicit val responseFormat = Json.format[Response]
}

case class Root(
  response: Response)

object Root {
  implicit val rootFormat = Json.format[Root]
}

val root = js.as[Root]
val apps = root.response.instances
```

As you can see, the case class vals must have the same name as their Json counter parts. Additionally, I used format instead of reads which is of course up to you, but most of the time you need both reads and writes which is what format gives you.

Comment: Would the type of this still be `Reads[App]` and could I use that still as the implicit reader for apps so that I can simply call `json.validate[List[App]]`?

Comment: oh nevermind, I understand. I need to use this with my implicit definition for `Reads[App]`. Thanks!